# Google Spreadsheet - Round down at 0.5, but round up above that

Tags: excel, google-sheets

The regular "ROUND" function will round down when < 0.5, and will round up when >= 0.5

I need 0.5 to be rounded down, but anything above that to be rounded up.

So:
10.4 should be 10
10.5 should be 10
10.6 should be 11

**Edit: Here is the solution i came up with**

If the value to be rounded is in B1
And the decimal precision is in A1 (0 = no decimals, 1 = one decimal place, etc)
`=IF(MOD(ABS(B1),(1/(10^A1)))<=0.5*(1/(10^A1)),ROUNDDOWN(B1,A1),ROUNDUP(B1,A1))`

The `ABS()` makes sure it works with negative numbers.
The `(1/(10^A1))` makes sure that my precision (which is a second argument to Google's rounding functions) scales my boundary condition (`0.5`) accordingly.
And the `MOD()` is what actually determines my boundary condition.

**Edit2:**

More elegant solution thanks to @Jayen

`=ROUNDUP(B1 - sign(B1) * (10 ^ -A1) / 2, A1)`

Comment: the 'more elegant' solution by Jayen has a bug. try it with .2 and you get 1 instead of 0! Also -.2 yeilds -1 instead of 0 too. Zero yeilds 0. But any number between 0 and .5 yields 1 instead of 0. People really need to test things out more thoroughly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is possible to create an IF statement that would do this **`=IF(A1-int(A1)>0.5,int(A1)+1,int(A1))`**

But seams a strange request, the normal convention (in the west) is to round .5 up, not down.

Comment: This is a fitting tool for EvE-Online (if that rings a bell). Who knows why that game uses round-half-down method, but it does. I will accept this answer, as i did end up using an IF statement (however differently)

Comment: xero seems to round a half cent down on my paycheck :(

Answer (score 2):

I'm creating `C1 = (10 ^ -A1) / 2` which is 0.5 if you round to 0 decimal places, 0.05 if you round to 1, etc.

Then it is simply:

`=ROUNDUP(B1 - C1, A1)`

Or substituting:

`=ROUNDUP(B1 - (10 ^ -A1) / 2, A1)`

**EDIT:**

Not sure if you want negative half numbers to round towards or away from 0, but is this ok?

`=ROUNDUP(B1 - sign(B1) * (10 ^ -A1) / 2, A1)`

That would be rounding towards 0 on the half.

**EDIT2:**

But in case you want negative half numbers to round away from 0 (all half numbers round towards negative infinity):

`=CEILING(B1 - 10 ^ -A1 / 2, 10 ^ -A1)`

**EDIT3:**

@ShawnKovac found an issue with my original answer when B1 < C1, so I've taken his and adapted it for any A1:

`=ROUNDUP(MAX(ABS(B1) - 10 ^ -A1 / 2, 0), A1) * SIGN(B1)`

Also my answer for rounding towards negative infinity throws an error when B1 < C1, so here's an update:

`=CEILING(B1 - 10 ^ -A1 / 2, SIGN(B1 - 10 ^ -A1 / 2) * 10 ^ -A1)`

Comment: Much more elegant, but it doesn't work with negative numbers. At precision `0` and value to round being `-10.60`, then result is `-12.00`

Comment: Roundup rounds away from zero instead of positively?  Egads!

Comment: Great that works. It's not fair to change accepted answer, since that **had** helped me 2 years ago when I needed it, but I will give you a bounty for a more elegant solution. Need to wait 23 hours, ping me if I forget.

Comment: The [ROUNDUP function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/ROUNDUP-function-F8BC9B23-E795-47DB-8703-DB171D0C42A7) rounds *away from zero*. The [CEILING function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/CEILING-function-0A5CD7C8-0720-4F0A-BD2C-C943E510899F) rounds *towards a numerically larger number*. Ask two mathematicians whether -2 is *larger* than -1 and you will get six answers.

Comment: thanks @Jeeped I updated my answer in case Slav wanted to round towards a numerically smaller number rather than towards 0.

Comment: @Jeeped, your statement claims that 'larger' is basically interpreted differently by different people (which i agree), but why then do you use that very term in your statement about the Ceiling function? It's like you admit there's a problem with the terminology and then you use the problematic terminology. And according to the CEILING link that you provided, CEILING "Returns number rounded up, away from zero, to the nearest multiple of significance". That's the same as what ROUNDUP does, according to all the documentation i read. I use LibreOffice tho, and i don't have MS Office to test it.

Comment: when i test CEILING and ROUNDUP in LibreOffice (which is probly the same result in MS Excel and Google Docs), i find that the documentation at Microsoft's CEILING page that Jeeped linked to is NOT the way LibreOffice handles CEILING. In LibreOffice, both always round up for positive numbers. But for negative numbers, RoundUP rounds down, that is away from zero, towards negative infinity. And for negative numbers, CEILING rounds up, that is towards zero, and towards positive infinity.

Comment: @Jayen, your formula (rounding towards 0 on the half) has a bug. with your formula: `=ROUNDUP(B1 - sign(B1) * (10 ^ -A1) / 2, A1)` if we take .2 or -.2, it yields -1 or 1 respectively. Let's simplify this by making a1=0, so the formula reduces to: `ROUNDUP(B1 - SIGN(B1) * 1 / 2)`. So when b1 = .2, when .5 is subtracted, it 'crosses' 0, which is not the intention. then -.3 is 'roundup'd and ROUNDUP(-.3) = -1. So 0.2 yields -1. :(

Comment: But Jayen, your method is quite clever. It's how i wud have thot it shud work too. I only found the bug because i tested many values in a table, from -2 to 2 roughly in increments of 1/4ths. My experience has shown me that bugs like this are very subtle, so thoro testing cannot be skipped, if we want it to truly work correctly.

Comment: the solution i went with is: `ROUNDUP(MAX(ABS(B1)-1/2,0))*SIGN(B1)`. So i used Jayen's clever formula, but used MAX with the ABS to eliminate the bug, then multiplied by the SIGN to allow it to work for positive and negative numbers.

Comment: @ShawnKovac I see that this has problems with `-(10^A1)/2<B1<(10^A1)/2`.  Clearly not the intention.  I'm updating my answer.

Comment: @ShawnKovac feel free to upvote my answer as you found it useful.

Answer (score 2):

Warning: this credited 'solution' has a bug:

```
=ROUNDUP(B1 - sign(B1) * (10 ^ -A1) / 2, A1)
```

Plug in .1, .2, .3, .4 or negative values of those to see the unintended results. The solution i went with is:

```
=ROUNDUP(MAX(ABS(B1)-1/2,0))*SIGN(B1)
```

So i used Jayen's clever formula, but used MAX with the ABS to eliminate the bug, then multiplied by the SIGN to allow it to work for positive and negative numbers.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the dataset, you could just subtract from your value, so long as you know that none of your numbers would be invalidated by doing so.

```
 =round(A1 - 0.00001)
```

Comment: Unfortunately it would invalidate some calculations

Answer (score 0):

=IF(AND(LEN(MOD(A2,1)>4),RIGHT(A2,1)="5"),ROUNDDOWN(A2,2),ROUND(A2,2))

The mod 1 will leave just the 0. and the decimal places. So if 3 decimal places and you want to round to 2, and the decimal has a length greater than 4 ("0." plus decimals), this  would indicate the decimal needs rounding. If the last digit of the decimal is 5 then use the rounddown feature else use round.

Answer (score 0):

well if you just subtract 0.1 it will work with positive but if you use negative you can use if A1 is lower then 0 add 0.1
IF(A1<0,ROUND(A1+0.1,0),ROUND(A1-0.1,0))

[A Table to show the result of the formula above ^^^^^](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o2yIE.png)
Hope it helped :)